# conversion dB into dB SPL

Tags: audio, sound, decibel

I'm using a sound calibrator (1kHz, 114dB SPL, GRAS Type 42AB).
When I got my data from my scope, the signal has 5mV. In spectrum mode, it is -50dB at the peak of 1kHz.

I'm using this preamp: GRAS Type 26CA, the attenuation is -0.25dB; 
and this microphone: GRAS Type 40AE, the sensitivity is 62dB/20µP.

How can I convert my dB value -50dB to dB SPL?

The correct dB SPL value should be 114 from the calibrator.

Thanks in advance, sorry for my English by the way.

Edit : here is the datasheet 
http://www.gras.dk/index.php/40ae.html       microphone
http://www.gras.dk/index.php/26ca.html       preamp

Comment: once you have nailed all your reference levels, the rest is easy. However, something doesn't add up. The pdf for the 40ae (it's polite to inlcude links to the data sheets BTW) says the mike sensitivty is 50mV/Pa, and that 42ab calibrator should be putting out 10Pa, so you should see 500mV out of it. Not sure how that 50mV/Pa is supposed to relate to the 62dB/20uPa you quote. Note 62dB is not a level, it's a ratio, so must be with respect to something, assuming something!

Comment: Here is the datasheet : http://www.gras.dk/index.php/42ab.html ,why the calibrator should be putting out 10 Pa ?

Comment: ... because the calibrator data sheet says it provides 10Pa, unless I'm reading incorrectly. You might link to that one as well!

Comment: I agree with you but the datasheet of the microphone say 50 mV/Pa at 250 Hz and not at 1kHz. The 62dB/ 20 µP is for the sensitivity to vibrations, we have to add the attenuation from the preamplificator too.

Comment: 62dB is NOT a level, it's a ratio, with respect to WHAT? Given I expect 500mV from 10Pa accroding to the data sheet, a max of a factor of 4 between 250Hz and 1kHz (does a mike respond to pressure or velocity? as the calbrator is quoted to deliver a pressure, I suspect pressure), and 0.25dB from the preamp, don't account for the factor of 100 to the 5mV that you are seeing (I suspect that's 3mV rms, and you're quoting 5mV peak, as the scope reads -50dB(v) (3mV!)

Comment: Yeah I think it's 3 mV RMS. But how I can have the factor of 100 ? Sorry, it's really new for me to work with dB SPL. Thanks for your help

Comment: Now the ratio between what you are seeing, 3mV, and what I think you should be seeing if I understand the calbrator @ 10Pa, and the mike sensitivity at 50mV/Pa, which is 500mV, that ratio is 500/3 = 167 is 44dB, still a long way from 0.25, or 62dB. I am not a domain expert, just a physicist. It sounds like the recording industry makes some scaling assumptions that neither of us are clued up on yet, or your mike is broken! 20uPa is the deemed 0dB(SPL) reference level, which squares with the calibrator's 10Pa being quoted as 114dB(SPL).

Comment: Ok thanks you Neil, I will contact GRAS about my result. I tried again and I have -65 dVB. So I will wait the answer from GRAS. I will give the answer here if I find the solution